# Suppress all output from a zsh function starting a background process

Tags: function, response, zsh

I wrote a small function to open websites from my zsh, however I fail at completely silencing its output.

My function in `.zshrc` looks like this:

```
function ff() { firefox "$@" >&/dev/null &; disown; }
```

Calling it from my zsh still outputs something (process information?):

```
$ ff example.org
[2] 27251
```

How do I need to change my function so that this output is no longer shown and why?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26534/how-to-dev-null-background-processes-informational-output

Comment: The question itself is answered in the comment above, but let me correct a few things. In zsh you should use the idiom `&!` or `&|` rather than `& disown`. Also, never put a semicolon after `&`, because `&` itself is already a terminator. Ref: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Jobs-_0026-Signals.html http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Simple-Commands-_0026-Pipelines

Comment: @Don Bottstein: Thank you for your comment, function works now as intended.

Comment: @ 4ae1e1: Thanks for your suggested corrections and the reference links, I adapted my function. Next time I try harder to find the respective sections in the documentation.